# Xamarin.forms nugetpackage conflicting and endless update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package, xamarin.forms

My app is a `pcl` app and it displays that there is update for following nuget packages

[image]
[image]

But if I update those, it displays that there is another update for Xamarin.forms package. If I install that, it shows again first screen there are 6 more updates. then it goes in endless loop.

Only difference droid project for xamarin.forms package as you can see before and after. It was downgraded to version 1.5.1.6571. Why is it happening? how can I resolve this endless update loop? I thought maybe it is the project but on another project, I have the same conflict

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the fix for that problem on xamarin forms on this [url](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57283/unable-to-find-a-version-of-xf-compatible-with/p1). there is even a video in the 2nd answer. it demonstrates how to fix this erro.

ANSWER ON THE PAGE:

Xamarin.Forms locks in a very specific version of the support libraries and google play services. You can't update them because Xamarin.Forms isn't compatible with them as it would need to be re-compiled.

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.0.1.3)

See the = 23.0.1.3, which means it is only compatible with that version number. This is just how NuGet works. When Xamarin.Forms updates these packages will auto update.

When you want to update Xamarin.Forms ONLY update Xamarin.Forms, don't update all of the packages. When you update just Xamarin.Forms it will update it's dependencies to the correct version number needed.

If you already update the other nugets that aren't letting you update, you could simply uninstall your packages and re-install just Xamarin.Forms.

Here is a video: http://screencast.com/t/U5FBj6KlH

Answer (score 1):

From my experience update all projects to `forms 2.0.0.6490`. It will then tell you that there is an update for the `xamarin.android` packages but they are not compatible with `2.0.0.6490`. Stay with `23.0.xx` for these.